# Why self is used as second argument of some method in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Object Oriented Programming in Python. I have been trying to learn the pygame module of python.

I have seen that in OOP , we always pass the `self` constructor as the first argument in order to bind the object to the method.

But here:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
      def __init__(self):
          super(Player, self).__init__()
          self.surf = pygame.Surface((75, 25))
          self.surf.fill((255, 255, 255))
          self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()`
```

In the third line , you can see they used the super method to call the `__init__` method of the sprite module . But why in this scenario `self` is used as the second argument instead of the first?

Comment: what you are asking is like why is this argument in second position in one function and first position in another function which makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply how `super` works.

See the docs here : https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#super

```
super([type[, object-or-type]])
```

The first argument is the class type - in your case `Player`, and the second argument is the object you are dealing with - usually `self`, i.e. the current instance of the class.

Note that you don't need to write this, you can just specify:

```
super().__init__()
```

And it is  the same thing when you're dealing with the current instance and the current class.